# C# equivalent of C++ std::string find

Tags: c#, c++, linq

I'm looking for the equialent of `c++` `std::string's find` in `c#`

So in `c++` you can have:

```
string s, nucleo = "ATGC";
s = "TCCCTCCATGCAG";
for (int i = 0; i < (int) s.length(); i++) {
      v = append(v, nucleo.find(s[i]));
      ...
}
```

How would nucleo.find in linq or loop would look like?

I currently have

```
int? found = s.find(nucleo);

public static int? find(this string source, string what)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (what == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("what");
    if (source.Length == 0) return null;
    if (what.Length == 0) return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (source.IndexOf(source[i]) == -1) return i;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
// The input string.
const string value = "Your dog is cute.";

// Test with IndexOf method.
if (value.IndexOf("dog") != -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string contains dog!");
}
}
}
```

Or may be you can use Contains

```
string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string s2 = "fox";
bool b;
b = s1.Contains(s2);
Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code makes no sense - it looks like you're re-implenting `String.IndexOf` yourself when all you need to do is call it directly.

C++'s `std::string::find` returns the position (i.e. character-index) of the first character of the first match (after the optional start position parameter), this is identical behaviour to .NET's `String.IndexOf` method. The only difference being that `find` returns `npos` on no-match but `IndexOf` returns `-1`.

Simply do this (if you want to use `null` as a value for no-match):

```
Int32? found = s.IndexOf( nucleo );
if( found == -1 ) found = null;
```